# Return result base on query result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I'm making an application which use neo4j as my back-end db.
I have this class :

```
class Person
{
public string Id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

I want to create a query that return 0 when person.Id exists in db (that means there can't be users with the same id exist in db together) and 1 when person.Id doesn't exist.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you,

**P/S:**

Neo4jClient or Neo4j query is OK .

I can convert Neo4j query to Neo4jClient in .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combination of `OPTIONAL MATCH` and `CASE`:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (P:Person {Id:123})
RETURN CASE P WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Also [`You can specify unique constraints that guarantee uniqueness of a certain property on nodes with a specific label`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_using_constraints):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (P:Person) ASSERT P.Id IS UNIQUE
```